# Check IE8 speed performance

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-8, http-headers

Does anybody know a tool, where you can test `HTTP headers` performance for Internet Explorer 8?
So if i start a log in request, i want to know how long the request need until he's finished.

Comment: Try Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fiddler and IE developer tools